# How to use helper method in environment configuration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have the following helper method in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_tenant
    @current_tenant ||= Tenant.find_by(domain: Apartment::Tenant.current)
  end
  helper_method :current_tenant
end
```

The tenant table also stores some information that I want to use in the environment configuration like so (this is `development.rb`):

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => current_tenant.amazon_s3_bucket,
      :access_key_id => current_tenant.amazon_s3_id,
      :secret_access_key => current_tenant.amazon_s3_secret
    }
  }

end
```

This gives me this error:

`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'current_tenant'`

**Is it possible to define a method which can be used in *views* AND *environment* configuration?**

Comment: You need to be more concrete and provide a **real** example. Generally speaking no, because it does not make sense. If you prove your request makes sense, then it may be possible to find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can't work - you can't use your helper method defined in controller in other parts, like models or (in this case) configuration. What's more, the code in `development.rb` is executed once, when the application starts. But you want `current_tenant` to be executed on every request.

BTW defining helper method as a public method of `ApplicationController` isn't very safe practice, since this method also becomes an action.

Comment: How can I define this method then which would allow me to use it both in views and environment configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and in this case it doesn't make sense at all. The paperclip defaults are designed to be request-independent, global configuration defaults.

In your case, you must leave the defaults empty and make sure to pass in your controller the proper configurations to the paperclip instance according to the user. [This is described in the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3).

Comment: Paperclip was just an example I put in there.

Comment: Is it possible to define a method which can be used in views AND environment configuration?

Comment: You need to be more concrete. Generally speaking no, because it does not make sense. If you prove your request makes sense, then it may be possible to find an appropriate solution.

Comment: Basically it's a multi-tenant app and I need to use tenant specific information in the environment configuration. This information is stored in the Tenant table in the DB.

Comment: Another place this would be needed: Devise initializer (to set omniauth token keys for Facebook and Google). These keys would be different for each tenant and stored in the DB.

Comment: As I already explained, the environment is a global, request-independent level. Tenant system is a somehow determined at request runtime. Therefore, the answer is still no. And as per your Devise example, again it falls into the same case of my Paperclip explanation.