# How to load module ApplicationHelper into config/environments/development.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to load the `ApplicationHelper` module inside config/environments/development.rb :

```
Rails.application.configure do
...
  include ApplicationHelper
...(here I want to call my functions from ApplicationHelper)
end
```

I need to call there my functions defined in ApplicationHelper.

But when I start the rails server, I get the error:

> undefined method `include' for #
>   (NoMethodError)

How to include the ApplicationHelper module the correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913810/how-to-use-helper-method-in-environment-configuration

Comment: Looks like it is. But stil no answer anyway.

Comment: What do you want to do in that applicationHelper?

Comment: `def result
  2+2
end`

Does it really matter what?

Comment: @prograils Since you are proposing to hop around inside the Rails boot process, yes, it will matter.  If you are using Rails constructs in the methods you intend to call, it may be entirely impossible.  Consider using an initializer that is a no-op in any environment other than development.